# Cannot add TabControl in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2017, tabcontrol, toolbox

I am in Visual Studio working on a WebForm C#/ASP.Net project. I am trying to add a component called `TabControl` from the toolbox. It should be found under the `All Windows Forms` but it is greyed-out. It is derived from `System.Windows.Forms` which is showing under my references in the project. In the `.aspx.cs` file, I have
`using System.Windows.Forms;` at the top as well. But I cannot add it into the `aspx` file either manually or by dragging it from the toolbox. I am using Visual Studio 2017. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: ASP.Net uses different controls than WinForms.

Comment: This way you can do it https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13165/A-Simple-ASP-NET-Tab-Control-Using-the-MultiView-c

Comment: Question @Arif : That solution looks great! However, I see it uses VB instead of C# in the last step. I use the VBToC# Converter all the time. There shouldn't be in issue just converting that part should there?